# How to avoid crash with Thread.terminate command?

Tags: delphi

Scenario 1) When I click button1 and then close form with X while thread is working I get "Thread Error: The handle is invalid"

Scenario 2) When I close application without clicking button1 I get "Access Violation ..."

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);  
begin
  ProccesSupervisor:= TMyThread0.Create(True);
  ProccesSupervisor.FreeOnTerminate:=true;
  ProccesSupervisor.Priority := tpNormal;
  ProccesSupervisor.Resume;
end;

procedure TMyThread0.Execute;
begin
  repeat

    //some code here

  until ProccesSupervisor.terminated=true;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormCloseQuery(Sender: TObject; var CanClose: Boolean);
begin
  ProccesSupervisor.Terminate;
  ProccesSupervisor.WaitFor;
end;
```

Comment: What is "some code here" doing?

Comment: @Blorgbeard Even with simple sleep(100) it crashes. 
@ Sami It must be more elegant way than simple try except

Comment: Use `until Terminated;` instead of `until ProccesSupervisor.Terminated`.

Comment: If you set `FreeOnTerminate:=true`, then don't use `WaitFor`, also using the `Terminated` property in a loop will stop working if the thread destroys by itself on terminate. Don't set `FreeOnTerminate:=true` and it should work fine.

Comment: Well, I imagine the EAccessViolation in (2) is because you never initialize `ProcessSupervisor` if you don't click the button, and then you try to `.Terminate` it in `CloseQuery`.

Comment: @Blorgbeard Is there any way to check whether ProcessSupervisor has been initialized?

Comment: Sure, just check if it's `nil`.

Comment: You can't hold a reference to a thread that has `FreeOnTerminate` set. Think about it. How could you know whether or not it has been destroyed.

Comment: You can use the `OnTerminate` event to set the reference to `nil`.

Comment: You can but so what. What do you gain

Comment: @DavidHeffernan the ability to hold and clear a reference to a self-freeing thread. As long as the main thread is the only one that uses the reference, since `OnTerminate` runs in the main thread. If other threads use the reference then you have a race condition unless you wrap the reference in a sync lock, like a critical section.

Comment: @remy But to gain what. If you are going to hold a reference then you have to clear it. And so you may as well free the object when you clear it. So again, what is gained?

Comment: If you use `FreeOnTerminate=False` then you must free the thread manually. It makes sense to free it when clearing the reference, but the problem is *when* to clear it. Some might wait until the end of the program, potentially leaving the thread object dormant for awhile if it terminates early. Some might want to free+clear it as soon as the thread terminates, but then you have to solve the issue that you can't free the thread inside of `OnTerminate`. So either trigger the free+clear asynchronously after `OnTerminate` exits, or else set `FreeOnTerminate=True` and let `OnTerminate` do the clear

Answer (score 5):

Never reference a thread object when `FreeOnTerminate = true`. The thread may already have finished its work and destroyed itself, so accessing it may not be safe.

In your `OnCloseQuery` event handler, you furthermore are accessing an uninitialized object if `Button1` has not been clicked.

If you want to control the lifetime of the thread, leave `FreeOnTerminate = false`.

In your `OnCloseQuery` event handler, check if the thread is assigned before terminating it, and also prevent a `Button1` click event to start more than one thread at a time.

In `TMyThread0.Execute()`, there must not be a reference to a specific thread instance when accessing the fields and methods of the class. Write this instead:

```
until Terminated;
```

Comment: Ok. Thank you all for you valuable comments. Now everything is working fine.
I hope this is how you check whether thread is initialized or not.

         if ProccesSupervisor<>nil then ProccesSupervisor.Terminate;

Comment: Yes that is ok. You can also use `if Assigned(ProccesSupervisor) then ...`

Answer (score 3):

Do not use `TThread.WaitFor()` with `TThread.FreeOnTerminate=True`.

When `Execute()` exits, if `TThread.FreeOnTerminate=True` then the `TThread` object destroys itself, closing the thread handle that `TThread.WaitFor()` waits on.  So you *may* see the "invalid handle" error.  Or you may get an access violation instead, or any number of other unexpected errors/symptoms, since you have *undefined behavior* due to a race condition where `WaitFor()` might be called on an invalid object, or usually the object is destroyed while `WaitFor()` is still running.  And `WaitFor()` raises an exception on any OS error, including the "invalid handle" error.

Setting `TThread.FreeOnTerminate=True` is primarily meant to be used with threads that are forgotten about once they are started.  If you need to reference a thread after it is started, do not use `FreeOnTerminate` at all.  You don't want the thread to disappear behind your back.

Also, `Execute()` should not be accessing its `Terminated` property via an external object pointer.  Use the `Self` pointer instead.

Try this instead:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);  
begin
  ProccesSupervisor := TMyThread0.Create(False);
end;

procedure TForm1.FormCloseQuery(Sender: TObject; var CanClose: Boolean);
begin
  if ProccesSupervisor <> nil then
  begin
    ProccesSupervisor.Terminate;
    ProccesSupervisor.WaitFor;
    FreeAndnil(ProccesSupervisor);
  end;
end;

procedure TMyThread0.Execute;
begin
  while not Terminated do
  begin
    //some code here
  end;
end;
```

If you absolutely must set `TThread.FreeOnTerminate=True`, then you should use the `TThread.OnTerminate` event to know when the thread disappears, but still stay away from `TThread.WaitFor()`, do your own error handling, eg:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);  
begin
  ProccesSupervisor := TMyThread0.Create(True);
  ProccesSupervisor.FreeOnTerminate := True;
  ProccesSupervisor.OnTerminate := ThreadTerminated;
  ProccesSupervisor.Resume;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormCloseQuery(Sender: TObject; var CanClose: Boolean);
var
  H: array[0..1] of THandle;
  Msg: TMsg;
begin
  if ProccesSupervisor <> nil then
  begin
    ProccesSupervisor.Terminate;
    //ProccesSupervisor.WaitFor;

    H[0] := ProccesSupervisor.Handle;
    H[1] := Classes.SyncEvent;
    WaitResult := 0;
    repeat
      case MsgWaitForMultipleObjects(2, H, False, INFINITE, QS_SENDMESSAGE) of
        WAIT_OBJECT_0, WAIT_FAILED: Break;
        WAIT_OBJECT_0 + 1: CheckSynchronize;
        WAIT_OBJECT_0 + 2: PeekMessage(Msg, 0, 0, 0, PM_NOREMOVE);
      end;
    until ProccesSupervisor = nil;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.ThreadTerminated(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ProccesSupervisor := nil;
end;

procedure TMyThread0.Execute;
begin
  while not Terminated do
  begin
    //some code here
  end;
end;
```

Comment: The second example is troublesome. If the tread will terminate in the middle of FormCloseQuery, there may be troubles, since no critical sections are used to protect the ProccesSupervisor pointer. It's better to not use FreeOnTerminate at all. What a pity that Borland have made sucha thing a troublesome FreeOnTerminate.

Comment: @MaximMasiutin: There is no problem, because both `FormCloseQuery()` and `ThreadTerminated()` run in the main UI thread (`OnTerminate` is called using `TThread.Synchronize()`), so the code does not need to protect access to the `ProccesSupervisor` pointer. The only time the value of the pointer can change is during the `CheckSynchronize()` call (when pending `TThread.Synchronize()` calls are processed), and the loop handles that condition...

Comment: @MaximMasiutin ... by checking if the pointer was changed by `ThreadTerminate()` before calling `MsgWaitForMultipleObjects()` again. Even if the thread object gets destroyed after `ThreadTerminated()` exits, the loop handles that, by checking if `MsgWaitForMultipleObjects()` returns `WAIT_OBJECT_0` (thread terminated but handle not closed yet) or `WAIT_FAILED` (thread handle already closed). The value of `ProccesSupervisor` cannot change between the time `FormCloseQuery()` is entered and `CheckSynchronize()` is called. And also `ProccesSupervisor.Handle` is cached beforehand to ensure safety.

Comment: You are right, sorry, I didn't notice that both FormCloseQuery() and ThreadTerminated() run in the main UI thread. The only issue remains that the cached thread handle passes to MsgWaitForMultipleObjects already closed. Is there a clear documentation of Microsoft that describes how must Windows behave in this case? Althought it is not exactly the case, but I have noticed that in Windows 95/98 if a handle gets closed from another thread while it is in WaitForMultipleObjects, the application fails with Access Violation.

Comment: However, this may not happen in this case, because OnTerminate event is executed in the context of the main thread, so the TMyThread0 will not finish in the background. 
The danger remains that this code logic is not very easy to understand from the first glance (at least I didn’t), and if in future anybody (team mates) will eventually modify the code, the troubles will arise. That’s why I don’t like FreeOnTerminate and advocate not never use it at all in our company.